# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {fullName})

Tags: reactjs, select, antd

I want to populate fields into a Select component from DB, i don't know what I am doing wrong here is my code:-

// state variables

const [employee, setEmployee] = useState([]);

**populate function:**

```
const populateEmployees = async () => {
    const { data: employees } = await getEmployeeNames();

    setEmployee(employees);
  };
```

**useEffect() :-**

```
 useEffect(async () => {

    await populateEmployees();
 
  }, []);
```

**Reusable Select component** : -

```
 <Controls.Select
          name="employeeId"
          label="Employee"
          value={values.employeeId}
          options={employee}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is reported when a normal object is passed as the children rather than react components or a string.

I would guess that `Controls.Select` uses its `options` property as its children.

So look at the documentation for it, and find it whether it expects a collection of `<option>`s or something else.

Comment: thanks sir i know how selects work ,however i don't want to render collection i just want the fullName to be populated in the Select component

Comment: @AhmedHosny A select component has options as its children, the error message suggests you are passing an object instead. You do not provide enough information for further diagnosis.